XSOAR run automation every hour
I'm trying to run an automation within XSOAR every hour. This automation checks for values in the warroom and automates different tasks per value entered by the analyst. The automation runs fine and does what I want, however I still need to trigger it manually with a command in the warroom.
I would like to trigger this automation to run every hour when it's part of a specific playbook. My guess would be to run a job every hour and link this automation to that job, but I can't find a way to do that.
I have a job that runs every hour. I have a working automation. But I can't link the two? Is it something I'm overlooking or am I trying to implement the 'features' of the app wrongly? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
